# Sort Outlook inbox by NUMBER of emails in a conversation?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I want to sort by the size of the conversation in my Outlook inbox.
I know it's possible to group by conversation but I want to see conversations with 30 items above those with 29 and even though Outlook displays this property (in the information bar per conversation) I can't work out how to utilize it.

Comment: I'm not seeing the conversation e-mail count in the status bar. Where are you seeing this?

Comment: If you sort by conversation, each conversation has its own grouping bar to expand and collapse the conversation. That bar shows a count of the messages in the conversation. It's therefore an object within Outlook and one which is calculated by the application - just not available to the end user for us to utilize.

Comment: In outlook 2013 I don't see this but perhaps you can in outlook 2013. Try slipstick, they've been helping outlook users for almost 20 years

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Conversation can be sorted by the other columns in your current view, but number of e-mails in a conversation is not one of them. This value is not fixed as it can change based on whether you bring in e-mails from other folders that are part of the conversation.

Comment: I'll accept that it's not possible but your justification is flawed.
All values are potentially fixed - that's like saying the count of unread messages in a folder can't be shown because a new message might arrive! Or the count of messages for a search folder - depends on the search results.

Comment: @Sun - I tried to sort conversations by size (Outlook 2013) - it showed the conversations in a very strange order. They were definitely not sorted by size. I am not sure what it was. So other fields apparently also do not really work, only "Received" works flawlessly.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're sorting conversations by size. When click on the Size column (at the very top), the conversation branch (the triangle on the left) goes away. Seems like Conversation view has its own sort order when you view in Conversation view.